# Inherited test class from generic base is ignored in MSTest

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, mstest, resharper-5.1

When creating a generic base test class in MSTest, and inheriting from it, I'm unable to run the tests of all the inheriting classes.

[image: Unit test results]

*BaseDependencyPropertyFactoryTest* is located in the *Whathecode.PresentationFramework.Tests* assembly. It is the generic base class. (*BaseDependencyPropertyFactoryTest<TTestClass>*)

Both assemblies have a test inheriting from this base class, called *DependencyPropertyFactoryTest*. All the inherited class does is passing a specific type argument.

```
[TestClass]
public class DependencyPropertyFactoryTest
    : BaseDependencyPropertyFactoryTest<ASpecificClass>
{
}
```

Only the inheriting test located in the same assembly as the base class seems to run. The inherited test in the *Whathecode.PresentationFramework.Aspects.Tests* assembly seems to be ignored entirely.

What am I doing wrong? When desired I could upload all the required source code, but you will need PostSharp for the aspects assembly.

---

As a test, I tried adding a test to the inherited test class in the aspects assembly, which calls all the tests in the base test class.

```
[TestMethod]
public void AllBaseTests()
{
    ClrGetterSetterTest();
    DependencyPropertyGetterSetterTest();
}
```

This gives the following result. Strangely enough this test is executed! For now this might work as a way to at least run them, but of course I don't want to edit this test each time I add extra tests in the base class.

[image: Unit test results after edit]

Why are those base tests skipped, and why the indication 'Aborted'?

Comment: FWIW, MSTest just sucks in so many ways that it's not even funny. AFAIR inherited tests classes are not supported... That's just one of many issues.

Comment: @Mark: What do you advise, should I give NUnit a try? I was quite pleased with MSTest up until this particular case, so if you'd say NUnit is definitely able to do this, I'll give it a try.

Comment: Just found [this relevant bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/466528/visual-studio-test-mstest-and-lack-of-inheritance-support-for-base-classes-that-resides-in-different-assemblies) on Microsoft Connect.

Comment: I'm very happy with xUnit.net: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/04/26/WhyImMigratingFromMSTestToXUnitnet.aspx while Roy Osherove seems to prefer NUnit: http://osherove.com/blog/2010/3/5/nunit-vs-mstest-nunit-wins-for-unit-testing.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The cause of this doesn't have to do with generics, but with the tests being in different assemblies.

A Microsoft Connect suggestion describes the problem: ["Visual Studio Test (MSTest) and lack of Inheritance support for base classes that resides in different assemblies."](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/466528/visual-studio-test-mstest-and-lack-of-inheritance-support-for-base-classes-that-resides-in-different-assemblies#) It is marked as 'fixed', but doesn't seem to be fixed in Visual Studio 2010 yet, perhaps it still needs to be released?

There is one interesting workaround to this problem:

> You can work around this problem by
>   compiling the source file containing
>   the base class into all test projects
>   that wish to derive from that base
>   class. Add the item as a "link" so
>   that you don't end up with multiple
>   copies of the source file for the base
>   class.

This worked for me, and I don't find the workaround too ugly.

Comment: VS 2013 still seems to be broken.  Filed new bug https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/989781

Comment: VS 2015 Update 1 - still broken

Comment: VS 2015 Update 3 - annnnnnnnnnnnd still broken

Comment: Curious if anyone has tried out the new [open sourced version](https://github.com/Microsoft/testfx) of MSTest to see if it has the same issue.  If not, I'd be happy to try to fix the issue and submit a pull request (when I have some time)..  This limitation is bugging me!

Comment: Gave MSTest2 a shot, and it still has the same issue.  The good news is this is open source.  I've [submitted a bug report](https://github.com/Microsoft/testfx/issues/158) and might take a stab at a fix.

Comment: Looks like there's [already a pull request](https://github.com/Microsoft/testfx/pull/147/files) out for this!!!  Woohoo!!

Answer (score 2):

Nothing special, but another way of solving the problem by calling base methods is:

```
public abstract class AccountBaseTest
{
    protected abstract IAccountRepository GetAccountRepository();

    public void _submitAccountToLMS_BlankAccount_NewLmsID()
    {
       Account account = new Account(GetAccountRepository());
       account.FirstName = Faker.FirstName();
       account.LastName = Faker.LastName();
       account.SubmitToLms();
       Assert.IsTrue(account.LmsID > 0);
    }
}



[TestClass]
public class AccountIntegrationTest
{
    protected override IAccountRepository GetAccountRepository()
    {
        return new AccountRepository();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void SubmitAccountToLMS_BlankAccount_NewLmsID()
    {
       base._submitAccountToLMS_BlankAccount_NewLmsID();
    }
}
```

Hopefully VS 2012 will fix this problem....

Answer (score 2):

Steven's answer of adding the base class source file as a link and then compiling it into the test dll worked for me as well.

However, starting in VS 2013 Update 2 there is now a concept of a "Shared Project" which is a way to formalize the idea of pulling in source code from another project into your project and then compiling them as one.

Here's what I did

1. Create new "Shared Projects" project
2. Move current test base class (and other needed files) into the shared project
3. Add a reference to the shared project from your test project (more on this below)
4. Compile, test, and be merry

At least on VS2015 Update 2, step 3 isn't as straight forward as I think it should be. Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33710617/1672027) Visual studio doesn't provide you an easy way to link shared projects to test projects (go figure...). This is what I had to do:

1. Unload the .csproj file,
2. Right-click and edit the .csproj file
3. Go all the way to the bottom and add this to the start of the `<Import ...>` grouping (fix path and name as needed, make sure to add `Label="Shared"`!):

   ```
   <Import Project="..\SharedProject\SharedProject.projitems" Label="Shared" />
   ```
4. Save and close the file
5. Reload the project

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed, and is shipping in the 1.1.17 release here:

Framework: https://www.nuget.org/packages/MSTest.TestFramework/1.1.17

Adapter: https://www.nuget.org/packages/MSTest.TestAdapter/1.1.17

References:

1. GitHub issue: https://github.com/Microsoft/testfx/issues/23
2. UV item: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/6030736-support-test-inheritance-for-base-classes-in-differ