# MS TEst: Method not executed when base class is generic

Tags: c#-4.0, generics, mstest, base-class

Not duplicate of: [Inherited test class from generic base is ignored in MSTest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002424/inherited-test-class-from-generic-base-is-ignored-in-mstest)

In my case, the test classes are in the same namespace/assembly.

When unittesting classes which have a lot in common, I would like to use a base test class with a generic parameter. I have boiled the problem down to the following, where my base test method is not being executed, but ONLY in the generic case.

**Non-generic:** Base test method is **EXECUTED**:

```
[TestClass]
public class DerivedTestClass : BaseUnitTest
{
    protected override string ReturnMeSomething(object obj)
    {
        return "test1" + obj.ToString();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void derived_test()
    {
    // This is executed
    }
}

[TestClass]
public abstract class BaseUnitTest
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void base_test()
    {
        // This is executed
    }
    protected abstract string ReturnMeSomething(object obj);
}
```

**Generic:** Base test method in generic base class is **NOT EXECUTED**:

```
[TestClass]
public class DerivedTestClass : BaseUnitTest<string>
{
    protected override string ReturnMeSomething(string s)
    {
        return "test1" + s;
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void derived_test()
    {
        // This is executed
    }
}

[TestClass]
public abstract class BaseUnitTest<T>
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void base_test()
    {
        // This is NOT executed
    }
    protected abstract string ReturnMeSomething(T t);
}
```

Can anyone tell me the reason for this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6002424/inherited-test-class-from-generic-base-is-ignored-in-mstest

Comment: Not same case. In this case, all classes are in the same assembly.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio (2010, 2012, or 2013)?

Comment: I use Visual Studio 2012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days, this suddenly works (!!). If anyone ever experiences this same, odd behavior, please write a comment here. I would suggest anyone to reboot and clean+rebuild everything and try again.