# Can't add Shared Project to Visual Studio Test Project

Tags: visual-studio-2015, vs-unit-testing-framework, shared-project

I'm using Visual Studio 2015

I have a Shared Project as an Independent Solution (A collection of Extensions used in several others Solutions).

I want to TEST the Shared Project (Independently any other solution).

So, I add a new TEST Project.

But, in my TEST Project I can't add ANY reference to the Shared Project (No option).

[image]

Comment: Having the same problem, would love a solution...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can edit the project's csproj file and at end of imports add an entry like

<Import Project="..\SharedProject\SharedProject.projitems" Label="Shared" />

changing path & SharedProject as appropriate

probably best adding it to another project and copying the row created there (assuming same path depths)

Answer (score 3):

Since a shared project can't be compiled on its own it cannot be added as a reference directly to a unit test project.

However, a work-around I've used is to create a helper class library and use that as a reference in the test project. In your case, create a new class library and call it **RobHelperTest.Helper**. This project won't contain any code on its own, so delete the *class1.cs* file. Since this is a class library, you can reference shared projects so simply add a reference to all your shared projects to **RobHelperTest.Helper** and then create a reference to **RobHelperTest.Helper** in your unit test project **RobHelperTest**.

[image: Screenshot showing the setup]

Now you have full access to all your objects within the shared projects.

Comment: It works, thx. Do not forget to add all necessary library references to the Helper project.